# How can I generate a Parquet file with bit-packed encoding rep/def levels?

Tags: parquet, bit-packing

I know this encoding is Deprecated, but I want to test the correctness of my Parquet reader, but I can't produce this file now.

Is there any way to generate bit-packed encoding rep/def levels parquet file?